# Disable time and date editing on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

Is there a way to disable time and date editing on a Windows Mobile device (via APIs or the registry)?

I have an application using the time and date of a Windows Mobile PDA and I don't want the user to change it (the time and date) - unless - he/she has some kind of administrative rights. I haven't find a way to do it with the menus. Is it possible to do it in any other way?

Thanks

Comment: this question is better suited to our sister site, Stack Overflow.  it will be migrated there shortly.  you will need to register accounts on both sites (with the same OpenID) in order to regain ownership of the question after it migrates.

Answer (score 0):

There are some registry keys that you can use to prevent applications running on windows mobile. Check [this](http://www.satter.org/2007/03/lets_shell_some.html) article out for the use of them. I used these keys a while ago to prevent the date/time being changed by preventing clock.exe from being run. I can't confirm this works with WM6.5 devices but it definitely worked with WM5 based devices.